# How can i train a data set with inputs that can be in different lengths in Accord.net

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I want to classify some dataset using Accord.net ann and svm, the problem is that my data set input arrays are not all in the same length,
each array can be from length 10 to about 64,
Is ther a way to handle such a dataset or do i need to make them all in the same size?

Comment: Can you tell something more about dataset? features It contained?

Comment: It contains numbers where each number belongs to {0,1, 2,....,k} where k is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your dataset composed of sequences of numbers? If yes, then you can use Hidden Markov Models. If you have a classification problem, you can use the Hidden Markov Classifier together with Baum-Welch learning to create a sequence classifier.

For instance, consider the following example involving data samples of varying length:

```
// Declare some testing data
int[][] inputs = new int[][]
{
    new int[] { 0,1,1,0 },   // Class 0
    new int[] { 0,0,1,0 },   // Class 0
    new int[] { 0,1,1,1,0 }, // Class 0
    new int[] { 0,1,0 },     // Class 0

    new int[] { 1,0,0,1 },   // Class 1
    new int[] { 1,1,0,1 },   // Class 1
    new int[] { 1,0,0,0,1 }, // Class 1
    new int[] { 1,0,1 },     // Class 1
};

int[] outputs = new int[]
{
    0,0,0,0, // First four sequences are of class 0
    1,1,1,1, // Last four sequences are of class 1
};


// We are trying to predict two different classes
int classes = 2;

// Each sequence may have up to two symbols (0 or 1)
int symbols = 2;
```

Now there is how you can create hidden Markov models to classify them:

```
// Nested models will have two states each
int[] states = new int[] { 2, 2 };

// Creates a new Hidden Markov Model Sequence Classifier with the given parameters
HiddenMarkovClassifier classifier = new HiddenMarkovClassifier(classes, states, symbols);

// Create a new learning algorithm to train the sequence classifier
var teacher = new HiddenMarkovClassifierLearning(classifier,

    // Train each model until the log-likelihood changes less than 0.001
    modelIndex => new BaumWelchLearning(classifier.Models[modelIndex])
    {
        Tolerance = 0.001,
        Iterations = 0
    }
);

// Train the sequence classifier using the algorithm
double likelihood = teacher.Run(inputs, outputs);

// Classify the sequences as belonging to one of the classes:
int output = classifier.Decide(new int[] { 1,0,0,1 }) // output should be 1
```

Comment: Thanks Cesar and greate framework!! does it works with continues numbers? it gives better results then using dynamic time wraping + svm ? as i understand the sequences have to be of a known length, am i right?

Comment: Yes, it works with continuous numbers but you might need to use a model based on GaussianDistributions. There are examples on how to do it in the Baum Welch learning documentation page. The sequences need a known length, but they do not have to have the same length. If you have sequences of unknown length (i.e. a stream) you can use the RunningMarkovStatistics and RunningMarkovClassifier classes.